# Override webhook URL with test URL in google actions not working

Tags: actions-on-google

Thanks for any help in advance :)

There is a possibility in the actions console, when testing in the simulator to override the webhook url from dialogflow, with a test url.

For testing I am using NGROK to access my node.js project running locally on my machine.

production URL: https://my-project.gcp.dr.dk/fulfillment
test URL: https://919cdffg53c.ngrok.io/fulfillment
(not actual urls)

The ngrok url is tested and receives request from e.g. postman.
But when i add the ngrok url as a test url in the simulator, it always defaults back to the production url.(To be clear, it visually changes the url in the simulator, but when it makes the request it uses the production url)

I have followed:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/simulator?authuser=1#test_url

I have tried for 10 hours, but without any luck.
The annoying thing is, it defaults back to the production URL without any message, so for a while I thought it worked, until I realized that it never even tried to use the test url.

I know there is not a lot of information to go with, in terms of helping. But maybe I am that lucky that someone has experienced it before and has a fix.

Again, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Are you using Actions Builder? I am unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same problem. Actions Console ignores the test URL and takes the one from Dialogflow every time. Did you find a solution?